# checking JSON Data contains media or not..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, validation

I am rendering the summary with JSON Data, in that i am checking for media.,
if media(image,audio,video) exist in JSON Data, it should render corresponding media to screen. so i am checking every value that contains media or not based on filetype. i've facing the problem while checking different data values

**Here My JS Code**

```
        var disp=[
                  {
                    "Session_ID": 1,
                    "column1": "http://dev.starport.in/phpupload/dentist.jpeg",
                    "Session_Name": "0",
                    "Session_Code": "0",
                    "Start_Time": "09:30",
                    "End_Time": "09:30",
                    "Staff": 0,
                    "Date": "/Date(-2188013400000)/",
                    "Status": 1,
                    "RowNumber": 1
                  }
                ];
        var mediatype;
        var media;
        var fname;
        $.each(disp[0],function(key,value)
        {
            fname=value;
            media=0;
            var filetype;

            if(fname.indexOf(".")> -1)            // problem
                filetype = fname.split('.').pop();
            else
                return true;

            if($.inArray(filetype, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) >= 1) {
                media=1;
                mediatype="image";
                return false;
            }
            else if($.inArray(filetype, ['mkv','mp4','vob']) >= 1) {
                media=1;
                mediatype="video";
                return false;
            }
            else if(filetype == "mp3") {
                media=1;
                mediatype="audio";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                media=0;
            }
        });
        console.log(mediatype);
```

Hence my code works for string and also render appropriate item, when its comes to other format occurs errors..

Awaiting Responses *Thanks in Advance*

Comment: why dont you try this: https://jsfiddle.net/jk5nsz4z/ . Instead of going through each object property just loop over objects and use .colum1 property and get your desired result.

Comment: i want to check all fields instead of column1, becoz i dont know which field having media

Comment: @keerthivasana: check this fiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/maverickosama92/jk5nsz4z/1/

Comment: @maverickosama92 thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will iterate over all the item inside the `disp` array and for each item it will iterate his `key - value`.

Your problem was that the first value is an `int` thus you cannot use `indexOf`. You should first check that the value is a `string`

```js
var disp = [{
  "Session_ID": 1,
  "column1": "http://dev.starport.in/phpupload/dentist.jpeg",
  "Session_Name": "0",
  "Session_Code": "0",
  "Start_Time": "09:30",
  "End_Time": "09:30",
  "Staff": 0,
  "Date": "/Date(-2188013400000)/",
  "Status": 1,
  "RowNumber": 1
}];
var mediatype;
var media;
var fname;

disp.forEach(function(item) {
  var media = 0;
  var filetype;

  for (var key in item) {
    if (typeof item[key] === "string") {
      if (item[key].indexOf(".") > -1) {
        filetype = item.column1.split(".").pop();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  var media = 0;
  var filetype;

  if (item.column1.indexOf(".") > -1) {
    filetype = item.column1.split(".").pop();
  }

  if ($.inArray(filetype, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) >= 1) {
    media = 1;
    mediatype = "image";
    return false;
  } else if ($.inArray(filetype, ['mkv', 'mp4', 'vob']) >= 1) {
    media = 1;
    mediatype = "video";
    return false;
  } else if (filetype == "mp3") {
    media = 1;
    mediatype = "audio";
    return false;
  } else {
    media = 0;
  }
});

console.log(mediatype);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE**

This is a very bad practice. You should know where is your media stored. It would be very weird to store your media inside `End_Time` for example.

The best solution would be to change your API and the JSON sent

Comment: i want to check all fields instead of column1, becoz i dont know which field having media

Comment: So the media can be inside `Start_time` for example ? If it is the case your should change your API. This is a terrible way of working

Comment: yes it can be any field., i will look at to change the API., if any other way possible..?

Answer (score 1):

Problem to your solution - work on backend and api structure.

Please follow below steps.

1. Save media properly on back-end. Let's consider your table is
   having two more fields. media_type and media_path.
2. Have proper JSON response which contains key as "media_type" and
   "media_path".
3. You should be able to parse this JSON response very quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much, great suggestion., but now i want to check all fields instead of column1, becoz i dont know which field having media to make my summary script as template. which suitable for all scenario

Answer (score 0):

Problem: indexOf is a String Function. And your code iterates through all the JSON Attributes. And they contains also numbers. This is causing the Problem. Maybe it would be better to navigate direct to the proper atttribute.

```
console.log(disp[0].column1)
"http://dev.starport.in/phpupload/dentist.jpeg"
```

My Opinion is that you should rethink your problem. =)

best regards Ruben